# In Flutter, how do i set the background of the (shaped) appbar transparent?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've used the following code to make the AppBar's bottom rounded:

```
shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(20)))
```

However, turns out the AppBar continues taking up the screen in the area without the primary color. How do i fix that? I want the AppBar to be transparent or something in the cut areas.[This is when this effect is clearest. there is a part of the image behind the AppBar that isn't shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NApym.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you want the cut area
transparent, set `elevation` to 0

Comment: It unfortunately did not work

Comment: i saw your image , this is because your image is not covering the area below appBar and the Background color of Your Scaffold widget is white

Comment: do you want your image to cover the cut area or give it another color?

Comment: i want it to cover the cut area. i assumed it should be done by making the cut area transparent but if there's another way to do it, i'll take it.

Comment: your cut area is transparent, behind is  scaffold background color

Comment: you can check it by changing scaffold's background color,

Comment: is there a way to make it so that the cut area shows the content behind the appbar and not the scaffold's color though?

Comment: actually there is no content behind the appbar

Comment: In Scaffold you can set `extendBodyBehindAppBar` to `True` this make the image cover the area behind the appBar

Comment: my code uses that already, i didn't include it but it also does nothing somehow

Comment: nvm. i just tried it in a simpler page and extendbodybehindappbar works... it will take some time but i know what the problem is now. thanks xd

Answer (score 0):

There's a property called **scrolledUnderElevation** in AppBar.
Set it to **0**.

```
 AppBar(
scrolledUnderElevation: 0.0,
    ...other properties)
```